# Mono: Soft Debugger/MonoDevelop + Embedded Runtime

Tags: debugging, mono, monodevelop

I'm trying to debug my managed assembly that's being loaded in native app. I've enabled Run With Custom Command Mono Soft Debugger in MonoDevelop, and I'm succesfully connecting with my app. However, the application hangs when it's about to hit a breakpoint.

I did some investigation, and it seems that it hangs when method is being called from another thread than the one mono runtime been initialized with. It is hit correctly, when run from the same thread.

I am calling `mono_thread_attach` for every thread that wants to call into managed lands, and everything works fine without debugger attached.

`Specs:` Mono 2.10.8, MonoDevelop: 2.8.6.4

`Edit1:` Tried it with trunk build of monodevelop, no luck. Haven't yet tried trunk mono build.

`Edit2:` Since my scenario is (roughly): main thread initialize application, then logic thread runs main loop, I detached main thread just before starting loop (`mono_thread_detach`). Now it works, so at least I can debug my stuff as long as there is one mono thread attached.

Comment: Seems to be connected: http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/Soft-Debugger-issues-can-t-suspend-threads-in-wait-for-suspend-td3236408.html

Comment: Backtrace the hung process to see what state it's in, most likely the debugger is waiting for some registered threads to stop.

Comment: Any hints how to check this stuff? When I attach VS debugger to the embedding app, it crashes when executing managed function with breakpoint.

Comment: The soft debugger implements breakpoints and stepping as segfaults, which it then catches and handles. Unfortunately the VS debugger interprets these as crashes, because it doesn't realize they're handled. You need to run the app, let it hit a breakpoint and hang, *then* attach the VS debugger.

Comment: Thanks, I've been able to check the threads (there are quite a few of them, and not all of them has got mono runtime attached - only 2 of them are calling into managed), but I haven't learnt anything meaningful from it. What exactly should I check?